# No está funcionando [Model]::destroy($id) en Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, ajax, model-view-controller

Tengo una aplicación que gestiona datos de almacenes. Guarda correctamente ( `Almacen::create($request->all())` ). Edita correctamente ( `Almacen::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all())` ). Pero al momento de eliminar (vía Ajax, con un ícono de bote de basura que retorna una confirmación y luego envía la request), la consola muestra un error 500. Esta es la sección desde la que se puede eliminar:

[image: imagen 1]

Al pulsar el bóton, aparece una ventana de Sweetalert (sencillita) que pide confirmación. Se debería eliminar el almacén de la base de datos y de inmediato la fila en la vista, pero en lugar de eso aparece este error en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he intentado de todo, pero no doy con el error. Lo último que pensé fue en los method que están por ahí. En el form y en el Ajax aparece 'POST', pero se supone que el `@method('delete')` de Laravel asume la prioridad (incluso la actualización también muestra los métodos como POST, pero el `@method('put')` los reescribe sin problema). En fin... Este es todo el código involucrado:

**El código del ícono del bote de basura (Vista):**

```
<form action="{{ route('eliminar_almacen', ['id' => $almacen->id]) }}" class="d-inline form-eliminar" method="POST">
    @csrf @method('delete')
    <button type="submit" class="btn-accion-tabla eliminar tooltipsC" title="Eliminar este registro">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash text-danger"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

**El JavaScript que envía la petición (con Sweetalert):**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabla-data').on('submit', '.form-eliminar', function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        const form = $(this);
        swal({
            title: '¿Está seguro de que desea eliminar el registro?',
            text: 'Esta acción no se puede deshacer!',
            icon: 'warning',
            buttons: {
                cancel: "Cancelar",
                confirm: "Aceptar"
            },
        }).then((value) => {
            if (value) {
                ajaxRequest(form);
            }
        });
    });

    function ajaxRequest(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(respuesta){
                alert(respuesta.mensaje);
                if (respuesta.mensaje == "ok") {
                    form.parents('tr').remove();
                    Administrador.notificaciones('El registro fue eliminado correctamente.', 'Administrador', 'success');
                } else {
                    Administrador.notificaciones('El registro no pudo ser eliminado. Hay recursos usándolo.', 'Administrador', 'error');
                }

            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

**La ruta en wep.php:**

```
Route::delete('almacen/{id}', 'AlmacenController@eliminar')->name('eliminar_almacen');
```

**AlmacenController (Controlador):**

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
    if (Almacen::destroy($id)) {
        return response()->json(['mensaje' => 'ok']);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['mensaje' => 'ng']);
    }
} else {
    abort(404);
}
```

**Y el modelo:**

```
class Almacen extends Model
{
    protected $table  = "almacen";
    protected $fillable  = ["nombre","num_id", "direccion" ...];
    protected $guarded  = ["id"];
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿cuál es el mensaje de error que aparece en DevTools del navegador o en el log de Laravel? Por cierto, no es necesario usar else en el código que muestras.

Comment: Intenta ver el error 500, ya que se refiere a un error de servidor, seguramente el error esté en el php, desde la pestaña Network del DevTools del navegador te habra devuelto un error, si haces click encima de la ruta del DELETE.